# When the app is in background, how to do I update the UI when user accepts CallKit call?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, linphone

I have an application that uses VOIP pushes to start CallKit calls. I am trying to perform a segue when the user accepts the call and I can't get anything UI wise to fire when the app is in this one state. I do have backgroundapprefresh enabled. 
How do I get a UI change to happen when the app is in background? I can see that the CallKit methods are firing.

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        configureAudioSession()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "IncomingCall"), object: nil)
        guard let call = callManager.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
            action.fail()
            return
        }

        call.answer()
        action.fulfill()
    }
```

Comment: You need to identify that you are on a call when your app returns to the foreground and perform the appropriate UI action at that time.

Comment: You can use `AppDelegate` function`func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {}` to do the changes before application enters foreground from background...!

Comment: are you using linphone ? how did you achieve the call  in killed state ? please guide me